# How can I show one function at a time and take input of return value in python?

Tags: python, pygame, python-3.6

I have total of 5 questions and I want them to be called randomly but my problem is that I am unable to display one question at a time on the screen and wait till user select the answer. The code I have right now is just switching the questions and not staying on one questions.

Below the code I posted is only the main part where I am having issues I am testing with 2 questions so in the code there is only 2 questions in random choice. The python version I am using is 3.6 any help would be appreciated. 
Thank you.

> GAME SCREEN

```
def game_screen():

    player_score = 25
    actual_score = 0
    wrong_answer = 0
    timer = pygame.time.get_ticks()
    seconds = 0
    start = True

    question_list = [question1, question2]

    while start :
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

        seconds = (pygame.time.get_ticks()- timer)/1000

        main_font = pygame.font.Font("ArialRounded.TTF", 22)
        sub_font = pygame.font.Font("ArialRounded.TTF", 22)
        timer_font = sub_font.render(str(seconds), True, SEABLUE)
        question_font = main_font.render("Question:", True, SEABLUE)

        star_img = pygame.image.load("starscore.png")
        menu_screen_img = pygame.image.load("quizzappbackgroundscreen.png")
        blureffect_img = pygame.image.load("blureffect.png")
        onoff_button_img = pygame.image.load("onoffbutton.png")
        knobone_img = pygame.image.load("knob_a.png")
        knobtwo_img = pygame.image.load("knob_a.png")

        knobrect_a = knobone_img.get_rect(center=(97.5,647.5))
        knobrect_b = knobtwo_img.get_rect(center=(514.5,647.5))
        mpos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

        if knobrect_a.collidepoint(mpos):
            knobone_img = pygame.image.load("knob_b.png")
            if click[0] == 1:
                knobone_img = pygame.image.load("rotatedknob_a.png")
                click_sound.set_volume(0.3)
                click_sound.play()

        if knobrect_b.collidepoint(mpos):
            knobtwo_img = pygame.image.load("knob_b.png")
            if click[0] == 1:
                knobtwo_img = pygame.image.load("rotatedknob_a.png")
                click_sound.set_volume(0.3)
                click_sound.play()

        screen.blit(menu_screen_img, [0,0])
        screen.blit(star_img, [50,47])
        screen.blit(timer_font, [485,55])
        screen.blit(question_font, [50,95])


        actual_score = random.choice(question_list)(player_score)
        #actual_score = question1(player_score)
        #player_score += actual_score

        if player_score > 25:
            player_score = 25

        draw_score(player_score)
        screen.blit(blureffect_img, [0,0])
        screen.blit(onoff_button_img, [25,726])
        screen.blit(knobone_img, [50,599])
        screen.blit(knobtwo_img, [465,599])

        pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Please create a [mcve] to make it easier for people to help you. You should separate the initialisation/loading portions of your code from the main loop as they should only be executed once. It would probably also help if you checked for collisions on mouse button down (or up) events and then changed your game state.

Comment: Thank you for your comment let me know which part you don't understand or which part of code giving you trouble because I can't think anyway to minimize the code because right now the code is only bunch of lines initializing the fonts and pictures and then displaying on screen which is basically the UI of the quiz app.

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess your specific problem is due to your failure to track the game state coherently or correctly. I have to guess, because you won't provide an example that exhibits the problem you describe and I can't run your code without generating a whole bunch of filler resources and guessing at the implementation of other, undefined functions.

Below is an example that *minimally* shows asking multiple questions, press a key to start asking and click the left or right mouse button to answer.

It does not require any additional resources to execute and, if you comment out the indicated line, will exhibit the same problem you describe: Cycling the question with every frame (without awaiting an answer).

```
import pygame
import random

pygame.init()
pygame.font.init()

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([320,240])
sys_font = pygame.font.SysFont(pygame.font.get_default_font(), 18)

pygame.display.set_caption("Quiz")
nums_left = 0  # initialise the  counters
nums_right = 0  
done = False

questions = ["Who?", "What?", "Where?", "When?", "Why?"]

# states: 0: init, 10: select a question, 20: wait for answer, 30: Answered
state = 0
while not done:
    # Events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if state == 0:
                state = 10
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            if state == 20:
                if event.button == 1:  # left
                    nums_left += 1
                    state = 30
                elif event.button == 2: # middle
                    pass
                elif event.button == 3: # right
                    nums_right += 1
                    state = 30
            elif state == 30:
                state = 10 # ask a new question

    # Clear Background
    screen.fill(pygame.color.Color("white"))
    #  Manage state
    if state == 0:
        question_txt = sys_font.render("Press any key to start!", True, pygame.color.Color("violet"))
    elif state == 10:
        # choose a random question
        question = random.choice(questions)
        question_txt = sys_font.render(question, True, pygame.color.Color("seagreen"))
        # comment out the line below to replicate buggy behaviour
        state = 20  
    elif state == 20:
        # we're just waiting here, perhaps indicate the mouse should be clicked
        pass
    elif state == 30:
        question_txt = sys_font.render("Click for a new question", True, pygame.color.Color("turquoise"))
    else:
        raise NotImplementedError  # shouldn't get here
        
    # always draw the score
    score_txt = sys_font.render(f"Left: {nums_left} Right: {nums_right}", True, pygame.color.Color("olivedrab"))
    # update the screen
    screen.blit(question_txt, (20, 20))
    screen.blit(score_txt, (20, 220))
    # Frame Change
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip about reading How to Ask. Next time before posting I will do it and thank you for your answer. I will try this way.
Thank you.

Comment: Glad to be helpful, was the answer useful at all?

Comment: Still making this code snippet work with my code but this thing has gave me an idea to make the thing work. 
Thank you.